# fs.createReadStream with pipe fires close event twice

Tags: node.js, express, fs, child-process

I'm using `fs.createReadStream` and the npm package `node-unzip-2` to load and unzip a zip-file onto my server and afterwards I want to use the folder where the file is unzipped for an executable. However I'm running into the problem with events, since createReadStream is both synchronous and asynchronous.

My upload code is the following:

```
    spacerace.post('/file-upload', upload.single('file'), function (request, response) {
    if (request.session.loggedin) {
        request.socket.setTimeout(10 * 60 * 1000);
        console.log('File is uploaded for: ' + request.session.teamID);
        var p = `bots/${request.session.teamID}`;
        deleteFolderRecursive(p);
        console.log('Folder deleted');
        fs.createReadStream(`uploads/${request.session.teamID}/${request.session.teamID}.zip`)
            .pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: `bots/${request.session.teamID}` }))
            .on('close', () => {
                console.log('File Unzipped');
                try {
                    var c = execSync(
                        path.join("server", "exec.exe") + " -i " + request.session.teamID,
                        { timeout: 5000, stdio: "inherit" }

                    )
                }
                catch (ex) {
                    response.send("Cannot test file: " + ex).end();
                    console.log(ex);
                }
                console.log('File Tested');
                response.status(200).end();
            })
            .on('finish', () => { console.log("part1done"); });
    }
    else {
        response.redirect('./login');
    }
});
```

The 'close' event is fired twice; ones after the `createReadStream` is finish reading the zip-file and ones after the `.pipe()` is done.

I've also tried to set the `execSync` part in the 'finish' event, however that is fired before the pipe (and thus the unzip) is handeled.

How can I execute the part inside the 'close' event only after the `.pipe()` is done?

Comment: First off, `.pipe()` returns your writable stream that you piped to, not the readable that is the source so you are not watching for the `close` event on your readable stream.  If you want to  know when the unzip is done, you should consult that particular module.  Please link to the exact module you are using if you want help with that module as there are a zillion different zip modules.

Comment: @jfriend00 as i stated in the first sentence, I'm using the node-unzip-2 module

Comment: Well, that module is horribly documented as it's just a layer on top of another module and you can't really tell from the doc how it is using the other module and therefore what doc for that other module applies.  It will likely take studying the code of both the `node-unzip-2` module and how it uses the `node-tar` module.to figure it out.